# How to create an arrow in Adobe Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've used an arrow like this:

➜

...in lots of programs - on the web in WordPress, in MSWord, even TextEdit.

But when I paste the arrow into an inDesign document, it's not recognised.

Is this arrow character not usable in inDesign?

How do I get an arrow character in an inDesign doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up on the menu bar, do Type > Glyphs if all else fails.

But I played with your arrow a bit - It's MS Mincho isn't it? As soon as you select that font in InDesign, the arrow shows up when you paste.

There's actually a setting you can tweak if you want to make copying/pasting that arrow work a little better in some scenarios: Go to Edit > Preferences > Clipboard Handling and check the radio button "All Information (Index Markers, Swatches, Styles, etc.)". I changed the setting to that from "Text Only" and while it still didn't work copying from the browser, it did work when I copied and pasted from Word. I usually keep that setting off because Word does some wacky things, but if it helps you then that's great!

Answer (score 5):

1) If you want an arrow character in *text*, you need to find one in a font (such as Zapf Dingbats or Wingdings). Your problem may be that you've pasted a character in a font which isn't carrying over to InDesign (that is, you copied in Wingdings and it's pasting in Times or whatever). You can't use code like "&r arr;" to create an arrow.

2) If you want an arrow *shape*, use the Line tool to draw a line, make sure it has a stroke, and then open the Stroke palette. You can select arrowheads from the dropdowns.

Answer (score 4):

Double click on the line tool icon to open the stroke and color windows. In the  "start" drop down bar there are a couple options for arrow heads. This window also allows you control the weight of the line and the color.